# Draw a path using a path sting in easeljs

Tags: canvas, path, easeljs

Is there any easy way to draw a path, by passing a string value representing that path.

For example, in fabric.js you can do something like that:

```
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');
```

Is there anything similar to that in easeljs. I looked at the documentation, i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tiny API on Graphics which is pretty easy to use:

```
graphics.f("#ff0000").mt(100,100).lt(100,100).ss(1).s("#0000ff").dc(100,0,50);
```

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html

For something string based, there is a "decodePath" API as well
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_decodePath

Its not verbose, as it is meant for tool output. DrawScript and Toolkit for CreateJS in Flash Pro both have support for it.

Comment: Thank you, i knew about the decodePath API but i haven't noticed that API on Graphics, which is a really neat way to do what i want to in my project. Thanks again.

Comment: is there any support for the encoded Path on inkscape for example ? or a command line that can do the trick ? :D